# Python scraping data that can only be accessed through Google OAuth login

Tags: python, web-scraping, oauth-2.0, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape some data from a website which uses Google OAuth for the authentication. Some data can only be accessed if I perform a login.

Basically, when you open the website (mamikos.com) and click login, there is no option for a normal login form, it will give you options to log in with facebook or google. It then will redirect you to the google login page. After login with google account, you then be redirected to website's homepage and all the data will easily be accessible with a simple click.

I am basically a noob, only know some basic coding and googling. I have looked everywhere but it seems like I am looking in the wrong place. I tried to write code with selenium to automate the click, passing username/password, and perform the login, but apparently, selenium is not the right tool for this as it will open a browser and do the stuff.

Is it possible to do this login and authentication process in the background? I got over a hundred thousand URL of pages in which I need the data from. Using selenium will crash my computer and will take a long time to finish.

Can someone here please show or at least point me into the right tools/library/method. or idk is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Please note that this answer is currently a work in progress - I'm working on (almost) the exact same problem, (different site, and I'll be using go), but I can provide a rough workaround for getting started, and when my solution matures I will update this.*

### Reiteration of problem statement

What you are asking for is a way for your scraper (third party **client**) to authenticate with a website (**Resource Server**) via google oauth (**Authorization Server**), to access resources that your specific account (**Resource owner**) has permission to see.

This sounds like **three legged ouath.**

["OAuth2 Simplified" is a nicely written article by Aaron Parecki](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/) giving a broad overview of the roles of **client**, **resource owner**, **resource server**, and **authorization server** in the three legged oauth process.

Another requirement (from what I can infer) is that the **client** you're implmenting/authenticating with is not trusted by the **Authorization Server** or the **Resource Server**.

This is significant, as it does preclude certain oauth flows from being usable, and may mean that various oauth client libraries/packages are not viable, as they may not implement flows for untrusted clients.

### Workaround (Rough pass)

You identified `selenium` as a potential workaround for achieving authentication.

You accurately identified that `selenium` is not a great solution for large-scale scraping, as it is very heavyweight, relatively slow, & uses a lot of resources.

This being said, you only need to use `selenium` once in this process - To automate the oauth process to obtain an access token to use the website.

Once you get a token, you can discard your selenium instance & use your favourite high performance scraping library to carry out the rest of your tasks. From there, you can attach the token to your requests and recieve access.

[This blog post](https://www.deliveron.com/blog/three-ways-get-oauth2-access-token-api-testing-azure-ad-secured-apis/) describes this approach broadly, using a JS selenium API (Under *"Use a automated UI Test to get the access token via Authorization Code Grant"* )

I will provide more specifics once I implement them.

Comment: Don't you think With `Selenium` one might run into Google's recaptcha pretty soon?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh , maybe- though I haven't personally seen that much ReCaptcha on OAuth flows- Usually third party auth is offered as a convenience & ReCaptcha goes against that. 

There are ways around recaptcha, too, they just tend not to be particularly scalable, but the goal here isn't to brute force an auth flow, it's to use a different client to complete the auth to acess resources the user owns.

Even so, there are actually ways around recaptcha

Answer (score -1):

I understand it can be tough to scrape data from such websites which are behind log-in pages. You will need to learn the basic replication of request that is being sent to the server through requests library of Python. It can be daunting in the beginning but you can learn it [step by step here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#authentication).

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is specifically about how to implement, a client in python (or whether a library exists) that can handle third-party oauth logins. Presumably, getting client credentials is out of the question.

The Authentication methods the `requests` package implements is very basic, and without significant effort is unlikely to meet the requirements.

I'm researching this further for my own ends, but my gut tells me that the easiest workaround would be to use `selenium` to get the token, and then pass that cookie to the lightweight scraper.